# how to find total percentage of specific value in whole data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas we have a function

```
df.isnull().sum() * 100 / len(df)
```

which gives the total perctange present of **Nan** present in all columns

How can we check something like **-999** or **0** present overall in df without giving up performance ,like without writing individual column code for calculating percentage by using **count()** then do that for all column rather than doing it **nan** way

Comment: use `df.isin([-999,0]) * 100 / len(df)`

Comment: The reason for the error isn't clear without data, can you please include that as well? See how to produce a [mcve].